# Is there a function that returns me the largest common divisor?

Tags: numerical-value

Is there a function that returns me the largest common divisor?

I tried this:

```
Intersection[Divisors[200], Divisors[280]] // Last
```

Comment: Yes, it is called `GCD`: Greatest Common Divisor.

Comment: Thank you. I was searching because I'm Brazilian and the acronym here is MDC

Comment: No problem. I'm German and it's called GGT here. =)

Comment: And just in case: `LCM` might also be of interest.